# How to show mouse pointer location using a mouse click?

Tags: mouse

I want to record my screen, and clearly show what is being clicked. You can configure the mouse to show the location when CTRL key is clicked. I want exactly that kind of behaviour, but only when the left mouse button is clicked instead of CTRL key.

Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at this handy tool: [Key-Mon](http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/)

If this is too small or not visible enough and you are not a programmer, ask the author or someone else to change the code here: http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/source/browse/src/keymon/lazy_pixbuf_creator.py

In [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/169426/62483) there is an explanation about how to modify the image displayed when you click.

Comment: It does not specifically locate the mouse (like the CTRL button), but it does work to show when the mouse is clicked. Nice to see it also shows the keys pressed.

Comment: It locates the mouse if you go to `settings` and turn on *highly visible click*

Comment: The link is broken. I'm not sure if this is the same one: https://pypi.org/project/key-mon/

Answer (score 9):

Please note first that changing to the left click isn't practical and may conflict with another key binding, like the menus.

**But you can use `ccsm` to initiate another key for showing the mouse location:**

If you don't have `ccsm`: [**Install From Here**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

You also need the package **`compiz-plugins-extra`**. You can find it in the Ubuntu Software Center.

**Go to CompizConfig Settings Manager > Accessibly > Show Mouse:**

- Under `Use This Plugin` left menu: check `Enable Show mouse`.
- Change the mouse `Initiate` key binding as below.

[image: CompizConfig Settings Manager]

To determine the meaning of Compiz button numbers, [check this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/90910/263353).

- Button 1 is generally the Left click
- Button 2 is generally the Middle or Right click

To take effect, you might need to "restart" Compiz:

```
compiz --replace &
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. But I configured: Show Mouse (in CCMS) activated; INITIATE: <Control> Button 2, and I went to Mouse configuration to configure that the mouse should be shown when CTRL is pressed. If I understand correctly, it should then show up when I actually click the mouse (left click>button 2), right? Because I see no change.

Comment: @Plua Sorry, I didn't mention that you must check the following: Under **use this plugin above in the picture**; Enable show mouse. Have you done this ? Also you don't need to go the mouse configuration . Just change it and it should work.

Comment: I tried using this in combination with the CTRL key as in this configuration: http://i.imgur.com/tBGcQ.png, and I also tried it without the CTRL key as in your example: http://i.imgur.com/LUfoz.png. It did not work. Please note that I'd like some indication of when the mouse is clicked (for a screencast) - not a mouse trail which is perhaps what this would do.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do this using the mouse options perhaps you will have to find some other.