# Determine what buttons are in CCSM?

Tags: compiz, ccsm

In CCSM, there are a lot of different options for mouse button events:

[image]

There are basically twenty different mouse buttons registered for my touchpad, presumably. How can I test to see which buttons are which? Is there something I could use which will spit out what button number I've hit so I can see?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It shows 20 buttons by default, which doesn't mean you actually can trigger 20 buttons.

To check which ones work, you can use the `xev` command.  Type the command into a terminal, ensure the xev window has focus and then try your buttons:

[image]

Button numbers are shown as highlighted.

Comment: +1, great answer! I just noticed `button 7` appear in the terminal, but couldn't reproduce it. Is there a way I could find out what caused it? I noticed that pressing two buttons together could cause a new number to appear, but I can't get 7 again.

Comment: certainly not with xev - I dont know of any other tool that will help.  sorry.

Answer (score 2):

On touch pad,

```
Single tap             - Button1 (left click)
Two finger tap         - Button 3 (right click)
Two finger up swipe    - Button 4 (scroll)
Two finger down swipe  - Button 5(Scroll)
Two finger right swipe - Button 7(Horiz. scroll)
Two finger left swipe  - Button 6(Horiz. scroll)
```

Answer (score 2):

I find `xinput` a little more convenient than `xev`:

```
xinput test n
```

where `n` is your mouse's device number. To find that number, use

```
xinput list
```