# Show position of pointer

Tags: pointers, personalization

There's an option for Ubuntu's mouse that says 'Show position of the mouse when the Control key is pressed.'. This function is **required** permanently enabled for a certain script I run, but on the other side it makes Blender 'Control' key not to work (as in Ctrl+Z, which is annoying) nor in some other apps (like the game Limbo). **So, how can I solve this problem?**

There are three solutions I can think of, but I don't know how to implement any of them.

- Change the key being clicked. If I could show mouse position with, say, Tab, that'd be perfectly fine.
- To show the mouse with a script. THIS would be the best actually (currently I'm using [xte](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte) to emulate the Ctrl key pressing). Running something like `show-mouse` in a terminal would be great. Couldn't find anything through google though.
- Make these programs to recognize the Control pressing apart of gnome/ubuntu. This is probably a bug so this should be the hardest way to solve.
  EDIT
- There is another option worth considering, I can send a gnome notification so it's displayed when I touch the screen on the main screen instead of around the mouse. However, it displays for a really long time, [which is a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/390508). It's worth considering in case it is solved.

Thank you so much!

PS, the solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49508/how-to-show-mouse-pointer-location-using-a-mouse-click) didn't work for me.

Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "This function is required permanently enabled for a certain script I run".

Could you elaborate? Just asking because you *could* use the Compiz Config Settings manager to enable the "show mouse" plugin and then get your script to use that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

to get the current mouse position. Then you can find ways to draw something at the mouse position.

Example usage using xwinwrap and ImageMagick, which displays 1.png for 3 seconds, but you may need to change some configurations of your window manager to make it work:

```
xwinwrap -g 100x100+$(xdotool getmouselocation|sed -r 's/^x:([0-9]+) y:([0-9]+) .*$/print \1-50;"+";\2-50/'|bc) -ni -a -st -sp -nf -o 0.5 -sh circle -- bash -c 'display -window $0 1.png;sleep 3s' WID
```