# alt+f4 script equivalent for custom keyboard shortcut?

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I would like to make a new **keyboard shortcut** that does exactly what <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> does right now. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

I know how to create a custom keyboard shortcut to execute a shell script, but I don't know what to do to close the current window like <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>does.

**Just to clarify**, I do not want to change what <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> does, but I want to add another key combination with the same functionality.

Thanks!   (*I prefer a solution without installing a new program, except an apt package*)

Comment: Welcome Alek! Please try to format your post in a more beautiful way.

Comment: I don't know if there is an answer on AskUbuntu, but this one might be what you are looking for:  https://superuser.com/a/757524/440143

Comment: What do you mean by "current window"? If it is a terminal, you can end the terminal session by pressing `<Ctrl+d>` (equivalent of `exit` command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/
and 
[Close active window from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183771/close-active-window-from-terminal)
where helpful.

You do have to run `sudo apt install wmctrl` but it it OK