# How to get cursor click effect?

Tags: mouse, customization, cursor

I've seen videos [like this one](http://youtu.be/CEUYvTwCGYE) in which a effect appears when the user made a click. What I want it's just the **effect** only, I don't care the colour of the cursor.

How can I make this effect when I do a click in **Ubuntu 11.10**?

Comment: the video link is broken, that video is no more available

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As indicated in [this very similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49508/how-to-show-mouse-pointer-location-using-a-mouse-click), your best option appears to be using *keymon*; it is fairly easy to customize it for an effect similar to what you see in your video.

#### 1. Install *keymon*

From [the Software Center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/key-mon), or via `sudo apt-get install key-mon`

#### 2. Make its window minimal and enable the click indicator

- The default window shows mouse and keyboard status, like:

  [image]
- Unless you want it, let's get rid of all these; right-click on it window, and chose **Settings:**. Then, uncheck everything under Buttons:

  [image]
- and set up the *Misc* tab as:

  [image]
- This leaves you with a minimal status window:

[image]

- And the default click-indicator, which you don't like very much :)

  [image]

#### 3. Customizing the mouse-click indicator and making the *KeyMon* window disappear

- First, let's make the *keymon* window disappear. Simply run it from the terminal (you can set up a launcher, script or startup too) as:

  ```
  key-mon --scale=0.1
  ```
- Next, the files we need to modify are in `/usr/shared/pyshared/keymon`, so `cd` to that folder.
- *Make the click-indicator bolder*: in `shaped_window.py`, find `win.set_opacity(0.5)` around line 58 and change the `0.5` to `1.0`
- *Increase the fade-out time:* at the end of `shaped_window.py`, find `gobject.timeout_add(200, self.hide)` and change the `200` to e.g. `750` (it's in milliseconds)
- *Change the indicator:* The indicators are simply SVG files, under `themes/*/mouse-indicator.svg`; you can edit these with Inkscape, etc. to customize it to whatever you want to be.

  - To get you started, I've created a red square like the one in your video. To "install it", just make sure *keymon* is not running, and download it this way (SVGs are just text files):

  ```
  sudo wget http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rBnUiXWh -O/usr/share/pyshared/keymon/themes/classic/mouse-indicator.svg
  ```
- Now start *keymon*, and you'll see a nice red fading-out indicator like the one in your video around the cursor whenever you click/drag:

  [image]

[**Youtube Video Demo**](http://youtu.be/bv443UFUJmc)

Comment: Thanks, now I'll modify the source and make `*.svg` files to customize. I also want to design an animation, not only an static image. Do you think there I can do this with a `*.svg` file or not? Do you know some program that can help me with this?

Comment: In general, you can use `inkscape` to create and edit SVG files. As for an animation, the simplest, if you can do with a small number of animation steps, may be to just modify `shaped_window.py` to quickly `show`, `hide` and `show` the appropriate SVGs, in sequence. BTW, please also consider awarding the bounty as it will be gone forever in a few hours...thanks.

Comment: for quantal the package 1.13 is broken; a working package I found [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/key-mon/1.9-1ubuntu2/+build/3589954), was a bit tricky to find..

Answer (score 3):

You can install [key-mon](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/keymon) which apart from showing the mouse clicks,can also show key presses.For locating the mouse-pointer you have to run the command:

```
key-mon --visible_click
```

Comment: The program is really interesting, it doesn't have the effect there I want but maybe modifying its source can do something similar.

Comment: You can get the source code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/)

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 20.04, I found the solution [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwBM_ThDNpQ)

These are the commands listed in the video:

```
$sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:nrbrtx/python2-stuff

$sudo apt-get update

$sudo apt-get install key-mon
```

and then you can check the option "Highly Visible Click "

[image: setting in key-mon]

Comment: Since August 2020, key-mon has been upgraded to python3, so you can use python3 pip to do `pip install key-mon` again (requires python3-xlib package to run).

Answer (score 1):

**Without having to install anything**, the only option is to enable *"Show position of pointer when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed"*

1. Go to *System Settings* > *Mouse and Touchpad*
2. Check the box that says: *"Show position of pointer when Control key is pressed"*
3. Done.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and an orange radiating circle should show the position of the pointer.

Comment: Your answer is very complicated and the effect isn't enabled by the click.

Comment: That's correct, the effect isn't enabled by the click. You need to press the Control Key **Ctrl** on the keyboard, which should produce an orange radiating circle to show the position of the pointer. It's not ideal, I know, but it will get the job done if you needed it.

Comment: Is not a necessity, is just a visual effect there I want. Thanks for you tip but my question remains unanswered. I want the effect by the click, avoiding push the Ctrl key all the time.

Comment: There's no such option in Ubuntu 20

Comment: For those who couldn't make it work after enabling this setting. First press Ctrl only (do not click at the same time), wait for 1s and then you'll see the effect. It's good to "pretend" a click with effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a similar thing with the Water effect in Compiz.

First watch a video about it (grabbed it on youtube): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pcLv8XuGKM  The results on the video may look like that it's not what you want, but you can change the settings later after you had enabled it.

Then definitely read [What are some of the issues with ccsm and why should I not use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

Then start.

First, install Compiz-Config by searching it in the Software center.

[image]

Then, open the program by searching **CompizConfig Settings Manager**.

[image]

Search for **Water Effect** and select the option

[image]

Enable the effect, set a custom shortcut by clicking the option on **Initiate**, then click on the shortcut that you assigned, then have fun!

The effects might not be the one you wanted, so fool around with the 2 sliders until you like what you saw.

Comment: The water effect lacks the option to be initiated by mouse input, am I right? If so, that wouldn't answer the question.

Comment: @Lucio  You might want to try adding some more details in the question.  Your title says you want a click effect, and here you say you don't want a click effect.

Comment: @belacqua "here you say you don't want a click effect" Where? I say that this effect is produced by **the movement of the mouse**, not by the **click**

Comment: @Lucio Perhaps I was misinterpreting your sentence "it isn't a click effect but a pointer effect".  I'm not being critical for the sake of it ; I'm trying to make sure your question is understandable and therefore answerable.

Comment: water effect is not there in Ubuntu 20.4

Answer (score -1):

On KDE Plasma 5.18 LTS / Kubuntu 20.04 LTS it's built in, no extra software installation needed

[image: Desktop Effect settings, click animation effect]